# ansible and sub loops

Tags: loops, ansible

Hope I have framed the title correctly. I am trying to loop over the first play using with_sequence and then use the output of the first play as the input of another, but the issue is the second play also uses a sequence. I can't get my around how I could achieve that.

create root directory

```yaml
file:
  path: dir{{ item }}
with_sequence: 1-6
register: outdirs
```

mount using above directory

```yaml
mount:
  state: mounted
  src: xxxx{{ item }}
  path: *outdirs.dir1*
  fstype: nfs
with_sequence: 21-26
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `results` from first task to loop on the next one and add your offset:

```yaml
- name: Create root directory
  file:
    path: "dir{{ item }}"
    state: directory
  with_sequence: 1-6
  register: outdirs

- name: Mount root dir
  vars:
    nfs_offset: 20
    nfs_number: "{{ item.item | int + nfs_offset | int }}"
  mount:
    state: mounted
    src: "xxxx{{ nfs_number }}"
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    fstype: nfs
  loop: "{{ outdirs.results }}"
```

Comment: wow..this was smooth. Thanks a ton. And I spent whole 3 days trying to figure out how to do this. Though I have no idea what the nfs_number key and value do?